# need explanation of postfix log send status

Tags: postfix

someone sent me an email but I didn't receive it this is what was in their log.  Can't seem to find the documentation / explanation of the message

```
status=sent (250 2.7.0 Ok, discarded, id=24684-20 - BANNED: Index)
```

I did find the RFC explanation of the DSN=2.7.0 but can't figure the remainder of the message.

Comment: Some configurations in `postfix` support a `discard` option, where the message is accepted from the sending server and silently discarded without being delivered to a recipient. Please post `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: I don't have the config for the receiving system they were just kind enough to send me their log message

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like whoever is responsible for managing your mailbox has chosen to accept responsibility for delivering a message and then not or not immediately delivered it, though the wording points to the former.

**Ask your *postmaster* to explain** - you won't find much more standardized information on this, because accepting then not delivering is non-standard behaviour, not typically appropriate for user mailboxes.
The standard expected behaviour is typically this:

> When the receiver-SMTP accepts a piece of mail (by sending a "250 OK"
> message in response to DATA), it is accepting responsibility for
> delivering or relaying the message.  It must take this responsibility
> seriously. -- [rfc5321#section-6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-6.1)

In an ideal world, mail administrators who chose to deviate from this expectation will ensure that the status message clearly spells out the problem to help with remediation in case it affects more than just the intended mail flows. E.g. if the action was meant to deal with a runaway process on the sending side, it should say something like  "discarded message matching recently received message-id from IP XYZ".